# fl_chart touch response issue in LineChart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fl-chart

I have displayed a Line chart using [fl_chart](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/line_chart.md#LineTouchResponse) `^0.10.1` (Tested on Flutter ver `52.2.1 & 53.0.1`).
I am updating the FlSpots from a csv file.

I am trying to get the index or `Spot` object if I touch somewhere in the plot.
But I am getting an empty list from the `touchResponse` if I touch (both tap or long-press) somewhere.

[image: console]

But I am getting the value in the plot itself. I am assuming it's there because of the built-in touch handler.
[image: plot]

The code I am trying it:

```
              lineTouchData: LineTouchData(
                          touchCallback: (LineTouchResponse touchResponse) {
                        if (touchResponse.touchInput is FlPanEnd ||
                            touchResponse.touchInput is FlLongPressEnd) {
                          var spots = touchResponse.lineBarSpots;
                          setState(() {
                            var lengthList = spots.length;
                            print(
                                'touched spot---> ${spots.toString()},,,len--->$lengthList');
                          });
                        } else {
                          print('wait');
                        }
                      }),
```

**My end goal is to use and pass the touched index to open a new screen/widget.**

Answer (score 0):

```
touchCallback: (LineTouchResponse? lineTouch) {
    final value = lineTouch.lineBarSpots![0].x;
    // set state...
});
```

It's in the demo by fl_chart in github.

https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/example/lib/line_chart/samples/line_chart_sample3.dart